# How to make the input codeblock different from the output codeblock?

Tags: css, markdown, jekyll

i'm keeping a tech blog to document what i've learned. (jekyll minimal-mistakes)

i commonly use python in jupyter notebook. so i convert .ipynb to .md for posting.

There is input blocks(python code blocks) and output blocks(default) in .md file, but I can't see the difference between the those.

I want to make a difference between the two blocks, but I don't know what to do.